# Get list of apps which play sounds

Tags: android

I think the question says it all: Is it possible to get a list of all apps which are currently playing sounds? Maybe over the SoundManager app or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your list by using this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1"); 
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : apps) {
        //process list here
    }
```